# Integrating Google Earth Enterprise to Android application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, google-earth-engine

I have Google Earth Enterprise installed in an AWS linux instance. I need to add Google Earth Enterprise maps to an Android mobile application. Is there an SDK like the normal Google Maps API for android. Also, is there any documentation available for integrating Google Earth Enterprise to Android application. 
Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Although there's no GEE SDK for Android, there are several possibilities for consuming GEE data in Android.

Although not a native Android SDK [Cesium 3D Client Library](https://github.com/google/earthenterprise/wiki/Cesium-3D-Client-Library) can be integrated, for example, in a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview) to build a hybrid mobile app.

It provides access to Tiled Imagery and Tiled Terrain, through the Google Earth Enterprise REST API, using [GoogleEarthEnterpriseImageryProvider](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/GoogleEarthEnterpriseImageryProvider.html) and [GoogleEarthEnterpriseTerrainProvider](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/GoogleEarthEnterpriseTerrainProvider.html), respectively.

There is also the possibility of [publishing KML in GEE](https://www.opengee.org/geedocs/5.2.2/answer/2760457.html) and that format can be easily consumed for example with the [Maps SDK for Android Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility)

Another possibility is [publishing a WMS](http://www.opengee.org/geedocs/5.2.2/answer/4441137.html) (Web Map Service), also supported by GEE, that can also be consumed using the [Google Maps SDK for Android TileLayer](https://github.com/shalperin/android-wms) (example of extending Google Maps [Tile Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay) for consuming WMS) .

I couldn't find the documentation for the mentioned Google Earth Enterprise REST API, so I can't say how easily Google Maps Tile Overlays can be extended in order to consume Tiled Imagery and Tiled Terrain from GEE